# Is there any way to check the callback from Intent share?

Tags: callback, share-intent

I want to call an API after the post is successfully shared on Whatsapp, Facebook, etc. 
below are the codes I am using to launch the apps.

```
Val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
         intent.type = "image/*"
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imagePath)
         intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,message)
         activity?.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"),100)
```